# how to get a sub list from a list in ocaml

Tags: list, ocaml

I'm looking at the List documentation. It seems the library does not provide a `sublist` function.

I'm trying to get list of elements from *i* to *j*. Now I have to write it as:

```
let rec sublist list i j =
  if i > j then
    []
  else
    (List.nth list i) :: (sublist list (i+1) j)
```

which is quite concise but I'm questioning the efficiency of `List.nth`, because if it's *O(n)*, I would rather have to write it in a less concise way.

I'm wondering why didn't they provide `List.sublist` func, if `List.nth` is not *O(1)*, because it's such a quite common operation..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
let rec sublist b e l = 
  match l with
    [] -> failwith "sublist"
  | h :: t -> 
     let tail = if e=0 then [] else sublist (b-1) (e-1) t in
     if b>0 then tail else h :: tail
;;

sublist 3 5 [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9] ;;
- : int list = [4; 5; 6]
```

The above is more or less a deforested version of newacct's solution. newacct's solution allocates an intermediate list (`drop i list`), which is possible for the compiler to optimize away in Haskell but much harder in ML. Therefore his version is perfectly fine for a Haskell function and marginally sub-optimal for an ML one. The difference between the two is only a constant factor: both are O(e). zrr's version is O(length(l)) since `List.filteri` doesn't know that `f` only returns `false` after a while, it calls it for all elements in `l`.

I'm not very happy to let `b` go negative but the version where it doesn't is more complicated.

One reference among quite a few for deforestation if you're interested: http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/topics/deforestation.html

Comment: Actually, I was wrong: the un-optimized call-by-value evaluation of newacct's function is O(length(l)) too, because of the intermediate list. To preserve the asymptotic complexity O(e) in ML, you would have to `take` first, then `drop`.

Answer (score 6):

Try writing the `take` (first n items) and `drop` (everything but the first n items) functions (like in Haskell) first. Then `sublist i j lst` is just `take (j-i) (drop i lst)`

Comment: Use an extension library like Batteries Included or Extlib and it'll provide take and drop for you.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit harder than it should be with OCaml's standard library --- the standard library is a bit sparse.  If you use one of the extended standard libraries, it gets easier.  With Core, for example, you could write:

```
let sublist list low high =
   List.filteri l ~f:(fun i _ -> i >= low && pos < high)
```

I imagine something similar is possible with extlib/batteries.

Comment: This will go through the entire list even if you just want something in the beginning of the list.

Answer (score 1):

While the answer provided by Pascal implements a nice candidate for `List.sublist` the right answer is that you should probably better use an array of a list.  The Array modules implements the `Array.sub` function that you might use.

While in many imperatives languages such as C++ or Perl there is essentially no difference between lists and arrays, this is not the same in OCaml where:

- Lists are better suited for recursive treatments and sequential access, *i.e.* is usually a better candidate as an array as argument to a recursive function, and you usually want to take a look at all the elements of the list.
- Arrays are better suited for random access, structure alteration (such as sorting), or for numerical computations.

Answer (score 0):

```ml
let rec sublist (lst : int list) (start : int) (stop : int) : int list =
  match lst with
  | [] -> [] 
  | x::rest when start = 0 && stop >= 0 -> x::sublist rest start (stop-1)
  | x::rest when start = 0 && stop = 0 -> sublist rest start stop
  | x::rest -> sublist rest (start-1) (stop-1)
;;
```

when works as if else statement